# hyperref links to wrong place on landscape page

Tags: hyperref, landscape

when I use landscape, hyperref links to the bottom of the page.  A minimum working example follow below.  When I run it with the landscape references commented out, and convert it to a pdf, I get the desired results.  When I run it with the landscape code, the link is to the bottom of the second page.  Has anyone encountered this?  Is there a workaround?

Thank you in advance.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A Section}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (0,0) parabola (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Somekindaplot  \label{basea1} }
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{landscape}

\clearpage
More text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replacing my phantomsection and addcontentsline code with this code did not work for me.  I get the same result.

Comment: Further experiments show that [h] works as is, but [t] puts the table above the \phantomsection and there is nothing you can do about it.   OTOH, the original MWE works for me just fine.